# How to create separate tests with Gradle and Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, kotlin, integration-testing

I am working on a Kotlin project with Gradle that includes unit tests. I want to add some integration tests (or functional tests, never understood the difference between the two), but I want to be able to run them independently. Ideally, the source of the tests are in different folders.

I am using Gradle 4.5 and my build.gradle file looks something like this :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'xyz.bobdudan.myproject.AppKt'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://maven.stardog.com" }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest:2.0.7'
}
```

I have tried the [method described here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing-with-the-testsets-plugin/) for java, but it doesn't work : the task also runs the unit tests, but they can't be found, and the integration tests are not executed at all.

What can i do ?

### Edit :

Here is the result of `gradle clean integTest` with the solution of @lance-java:

```
:clean
:compileIntegTestKotlin
:compileIntegTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processIntegTestResources NO-SOURCE
:integTestClasses UP-TO-DATE
:integTest NO-SOURCE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

So nothing is executed (I make sure that the tests are supposed to fail)

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not a kotlin dev so will write in groovy.

You can add another `SourceSet` which will automatically add a [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) task for the `SourceSet` and also a few [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) instances to the model (eg integTestCompile, integTestCompileOnly, integTestRuntime etc)

```
sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/integTest/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/integTest/resources'
    }
}
configurations {
    integTestCompile.extendsFrom compile
}
```

Then you can add another `Test` task

```
task integTest(type: Test) {  
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

You may wish to wire the `integTest` task into the normal `DAG`, or perhaps you'll leave this off and call it explicitly

```
check.dependsOn integTest
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work. The update on my post shows the output of the command `gradle clean integTest`

Comment: `:integTest NO-SOURCE` means there's nothing in `src/integTest/java` so it didn't do anything. See also [nebula-integtest-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-project-plugin#nebula-integtest-plugin) which does everything I've mentioned using a single line

Comment: I don't think so, because I explicitly declared the source directory and if I make a mistake in the file it will not compile.

Comment: Have you put a `.java` file (with a junit `@Test` annotation) in `src/integTest/java`?

Answer (score 1):

To tell long story short you have to:

1. create separate source sets,
2. create testTask for each test source,
3. set it up,
4. define order these tasks should be executed during build/check

and you are good to go.

**Here is a guide** in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299968/1824898) about how to do this for project using `JUnit5` and `Kotlin Spek` test framework.